# How to migrate SonarQube 6.7 from MySQL to postgresql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, sonarqube

We need to migrate SonarQube from MySQL to posgresql.

To achieve this, I would export from MySQL and import to postgresql. This I can handle, there are more than enough manuals for this and also I'm OK with database magic ;)

However, my question is: would that work for SonarQube in general? Does SonarQube use some database-specific magic that would eliminate the ability to migrate?

Steffen

Answer (score 1):

Good news : there is no specific database magic used in SonarQube.

However, note that some column have different types due to limitation on some database (for instance, the boolean type).

So if you want to migrate from MySQL to Postgresql, I highly suggest to let SonarQube create the schema first (and with same version of SonarQube than the one used with MySQL) and then do the migration, but you may need to adjust some migration for some of the column (again probably for boolean type).