# How to migrate from version in Sonar from MySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sonarqube

I have a question about the migration of versions in Sonar, to see if you can solve it.

I have Sonar 5.2 with MySQL and I want to update to 6.1 and move to PostgreSQL. From what I've been reading, I think the best way is to perform the required update, create a Squema in the new Sonar and then import the database I had in the old Sonar ...

is this correct?

Greetings, Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

It's possible but not that easy but it's doable.

You can find some details here : [How to migrate SonarQube 6.7 from MySQL to postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47412263/how-to-migrate-sonarqube-6-7-from-mysql-to-postgresql/47416038#47416038)

Comment: Yes, I read that post yesterday and asked if it was like I thought then ... but I was told to open another post to be a question.

Perfect, then the steps to follow would be:

1. Update the version you want, in this case the 6.1.
2. Create the DB system in the new updated Sonar.
3. Pass the MySQL database to PostgresQL

I'm right?

Thank you very much for answering :)

Comment: Exact, please note that storage of some values may differ between databases.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Thank you very much for your quick help :D

Comment: Good again,

a question ... looking for I got this: Sonar DB Copy Tool
Is it what we need to perform the migration between databases?
Thanks :)

Comment: Exact ! Note that https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Sonar+DB+Copy+Tool is part of  the Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Good Morning,

Do you know if there is another alternative to migrate the tables?

The version I have installed on Sonar is not the Enterprise, and I think I will not be able to use this tool. I feel so much question, I am very new in this :(

A greeting

Comment: you can use https://github.com/SonarSource/mysql-migrator as a FOSS mysql migrator tool to migrate your database from MySQL to PostgreSQL